# BufferedReader Blocking on readLine()

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

For some reason I am not able to read lines from the client on the server. The client is able to send lines without a problem but the server wont move past the **first time clientIn.readLine() is called**. I assume it is blocking but I don't know how to deal with it.

This also occurred when I sent lines without the server side loop.

Client.java

```
public void run()
{
     try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        System.out.println("Client connected on port: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        //wrap streams for ease 
        BufferedReader serverIn =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter serverOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
        System.out.println("starting messages");

        //send messages 
        serverOut.println("hello from: " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
        serverOut.println("msg1: " + this.hashCode());
        serverOut.println("msg2: final test");
        //close the connection
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server.java:

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Server Running on port: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            //listen for connections
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            //record sockets 
            connections.put(client.getRemoteSocketAddress(), client);

            //wrap streams for ease 
            BufferedReader clientIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter clientOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())));

            //send messages
            String line = null;
            while((line = clientIn.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            //ends the connection
            client.close();
            System.out.println("Client disconnected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
socket.close();
```

You are closing the socket where you should be closing the `PrintWriter`:

```
serverOut.close();
```

You're losing buffered data in the `PrintWriter` when you close the socket out from under it.

Comment: So closing the socket week terminate the connection and close the iostreams but not flush the data in the buffer to the remote end?

Answer (score 3):

You need to `flush()` your `serverOut` writer, otherwise your messages stay in the buffer of the BufferedWriter and are never sent to the server.

Comment: I understand print writer has an internal buffer for sending data, but how long does it take to send it on it's own. Or will it always wait for you to flush?

Comment: It's not just the PrintWriter, it's also the BufferedWriter. And the time doesn't matter. The PrintWriter and the BufferedWriter will only write when their buffer are full. See the javadoc.